# Setting a path HTTP GET Request using curl on PHP, for web API

Tags: php, http, curl, http-headers, httprequest

I'm working on a web_app using teamviewer API. According to the [documentation](http://download.teamviewer.com/integrate/TeamViewer_API_Documentation.pdf), it works using HTTP requests (GET, POST, etc..).

I don't get how to make a request on PHP using CURL. The documentation said to do this:

```
POST /api/v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: webapi.teamviewer.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

so I wrote this

```
$url = 'webapi.teamviewer.com';
$headers = array(
    'GET /api/v1/oauth2/authorize HTTP/1.1',
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
);
//data
$data = [
    'response_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https%3A%2F%2FTesting%2Ecom%2F',
    'client_id'   => '65671-XDdsxUNyxGmskcJHQgLC'
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

I just can't figure out how to indicate the request the `HTTP/1.1` and the path `/api/v1/oauth2/authorize`. I'm putting it in the header but I'm sure it doesn't go there.

I use to work on embedded C and I remember that first you connect to the host and then write GET path HTTP/1.1 as a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$url` should be the full path, just like a normal URL. So it would be

```
$url = 'webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/oauth2/authorize';
```

And you can remove the `GET ...` part from `$headers`, because the URL (path) doesn't go in there.

That should work after that. If you want to see more info about the curl connection and what's going on, add this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

The full list of curl options is at the [PHP manual page on `curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).